# Motion Detection by Yolo and Tracker's data

Tags: python, yolo, motion, tracker

I have been struggling for a long time with the problem of creating a reliable algorithm that detects the movement of objects in a scene. I am constrained by the use of Yolo and a tracker (for example bytetrack).

My problem is to determine whether an object detected in the scene is stationary or moving, using data from the tracker such as ID, bbox position, etc.

As you can imagine, it should be able to cover a wide range of different situations and different motions, but my question, to begin with, is: Is there already an algorithm that does this kind of work?

Imagine that the tracker gives you for each object detected in the scene its ID, the position of its bbox, dimensions, etc., and that the algorithm, analyzing the data of each object, understands whether the object is moving or is stationary (over time).

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: I don't understand why all the YOLO questions are getting closed. Take a look at the Darknet/YOLO helper library DarkHelp.  The tracker class in DarkHelp would tell you if  objects are moving.  Another route would be to use the PSNR signal-to-noise algorithm, as it is used in the Move Detection library here:  https://github.com/stephanecharette/MoveDetect/blob/master/src-lib/MoveDetect.hpp#L14-L21